# C++: vector<string> to char array

Tags: c++

I'm creating basic ldap server as school project. I'm sending ldap message to client (bindResponse, searchResEntry, searchResDone) as `vector<char> searchResDone;`

**Declaration:**

```
vector<char> searchResDone = {0x30, 0x0c, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x65, 0x07, 0x0a, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00};
```

**Function:**

```
void sendResponse(int newsock, char response[], int msg_size){
  int i = write(newsock,response,msg_size);// send message to the client
  if (i == -1){ // check if data was successfully sent out
    err(1,"write() failed.");
  }
  else if (i != msg_size){
    err(1,"write(): buffer written partially");
  }
}
```

**Call:**

```
sendResponse(newsock,reinterpret_cast<char*>(searchResDone.data()), searchResDone.size());
```

.

**Problem:**

I am decomposing searchRequest from client, then analysing and building it as

```
vector<string> response;
```

What I don't know is to send response as `vector<string>` (`vector<string> vcStr; vcStr[0] is for example 0x30`) and I'm not able to convert it to `vector<char>` ..I only managed to convert one string from vector to char array as {0,x,3,0,...} but I need one hex number as one char as you can see higher.

I tried to resolve this by myself but I'm out of ideas.

**UPDATE:**
Client is asking for Name of user with mail `mail=my.mail@mail.com` 
I have parsed name, login, mail in same order (`name[1],login[1],mail[1]`) to `vector<string>` so if I will receive `mail=my.mail@mail.com`

I am using regex when looping through `vector<string> mail` then I know if `mail[1]` matches, I can take name from `name[1]` .. then I will take that `name[1]` convert it to hex numbers and I need to store it in some array `{0x30, 0x0c,..}`, combine same type arrays together and send it to client as one big array `{0x30, 0x0c,..}`

Comment: Could you please post a sample of code that is not working or what you're trying to do in code-like form?

Comment: You mean `vcStr.c_str()` or  `vcStr[0].c_str()` ?

Comment: We could certainly compose a `std::vector<char>` from a `std::vector<string>` for you, but that sounds like a design flaw, and there isn't enough context in your post to say otherwise. Tell us more about `searchRequest`; how it is created, and what you're using it for.

Comment: @stark: That (the first one) will give a c-style array of `std::string`, not of `char`. There is no "simple" way to go from vector<string> to vector<char> because all the strings are on the heap somewhere not in a contiguous fashion.

Comment: searchRequest is not that relevant but its message from client in hex numbers. I am decoding it to know what I have to search and send back to client. 
for example client is asking Name of User having `'(mail=my.mail@mail.com)'`
then I am parsing csv utf-8 file which looks like:
`Firstname Lastname; login; my.mail@mail.com`
I have to build hex message from end to front because I have to check for length after almost every element.
it looks like this:
`<lenght to end in hexa> 0x04, <lenght of mail in hexa>, <mail in hexa>`
Then I need to send message to client as {0x30, 0x0c, .... }

Comment: I have parsed name,login,mail in same order (`name[1],login[1],mail[1]) to `vector<string>` so if I will receive `mail=my.mail@mail.com` I am using regex when looping through `vector<string> mail` then I know `if mail[1] matches`, I can take name from `name[1]` .. then I will take that `name[1]` convert it to hex numbers and I need to store it in some array `{0x30, 0x0c,..}`, combine same type arrays together and send it to client as one big array `{0x30, 0x0c,..}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By far* the easiest solution is to call `sendResponse` repeatedly, on every `string` in your `vector<string>`. The destination is a socket, and almost certainly that is a stream (not message) socket. The other side of a stream socket cannot see how often you called `sendResponse`; they just see a stream of bytes.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly I didn't know that I can send ldap message only as one array but also in loop. Adding solution to end of my question. Thanks again!

Comment: @MrVopi: It's not just LDAP. Any protocol that sends messages on top of a stream protocol must insert its own message delimiters. Whether that's `{ }` for JSON or `< >` for XML, the other end can't know whether you sent the begin and end in the same `write()`.